# How to convert jee transactions to spring transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a code snippet that needs to be converted to spring data jpa, as below.

The code uses EntityManager to get current transaction, if it is active then rollbacks the transaction. If not then creates a new transaction and persists the records.

```
EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
if (transaction.isActive()) {
    transaction.rollback();
}
transaction.begin();
for (Iterator<AuditEntity> it = auditLogs.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    AuditEntity enquiry = it.next();
    entityManager.persist(enquiry);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
}
transaction.commit();
```

How can I make this be using string data jpa and hibernate?

Comment: Just use the entitymanager, and remove the transactional code and add an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Create repository bean, spring will generate implementation
   interface AditLogRepository extends CrudRepository<AuditEntity, Long> {}

   // Inject repository bean, spring will do it automatically on startup
   @Autowired AditLogRepository repository;
   
   // Use Transactional annotation, spring will begin transaction, commit or rolback in case of RuntimeException
   @Transactional
   void saveAll(Collection<AuditEntity> auditLogs) {
      for (AuditEntity entity : auditLogs) {
        repository.save(entity);
      }
   }
```

Comment: How to test this condition                                                                                                       if (transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.rollback();
        } or is ot not required.

Comment: The `flush` and `clear` don't appear here and removing them can be dangerous especially with large collections removing those will cripple your performance.

Comment: You can use saveAndFlush and detach.

Comment: How to manually clear ? or is it needed?  as I see repository does not have any method for clear.

Comment: @PersistenceContext protected EntityManager entityManager;
You can inject entityManager and clear it.